# How to turn object into this for sculpting?

Tags: mesh, objects, sculpting

[image]
[image]

Hi.I'm trying to make a realistic looking model and i watched a few tutorials and they used the 2nd cube for scuplting.But they didn't mention how to get the 2nd cube.Can anyone tell me what's the name of the 2nd cube and how to turn the 1st cube to the 2nd cube?

Comment: can you indicate a link to the tutorials you are talking about ?

Answer (score 2):

Without additional information, I would bet on "smooth shading" set on the cube (tool shelf on the left of the 3d view), it is not a 'different' cube.
It seems also having a subsurface modifier ('simple' method) on.
Try to switch back and forth between smooth and flat and you'll see the shading difference.
hope it helps